# Keep text block in view while scrolling in window phone 8.1 Runtime

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

[my problem is exactly similar to this article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27772.windows-phone-how-to-keep-a-ui-element-in-view-when-scrolling-a-page-in-windows-phone.aspx)

But I need to implement in wp8.1 runtime. I want textblock (name=txt_latest_update) in view while scrolling

here is my XAML code

```
<Grid Name="Root_content" Background="#FFF7FDF7">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>          
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">
        <Image Source="/Assets/nepaltoday.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>     
    </Border>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"   Name="frontpage_scrollview" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                  >            
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Image Name="startscren"  Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.3,0" EndPoint="1,0.">
                                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1.2" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,10,0">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Name="txt_nepali_date" Foreground="White" FontSize="26"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="txt_eng_date" Foreground="White" FontSize="26" />
                            <TextBlock Name="txt_temp"  Foreground="Yellow" FontSize="44" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="txt_location" FontSize="22"/>                       
                       </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-20"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                        <Button Name="btnNews" Click="btnNews_Click">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/FrontPage/horoscope.png" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Name="btnHoroscope" Click="btnHoroscope_Click">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/FrontPage/horoscope.png"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Name="btnCurrencyExchanges" Click="btnCurrencyExchanges_Click">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/FrontPage/currency exchange.png"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Name="btnStockExchanges" Click="btnStockExchange">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/FrontPage/on this day.png"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Name="btnOnthisday" Click="btnOnthisday_Click">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/FrontPage/horoscope.png"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Name="btnMovie" Click="btnMovie_Click">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/FrontPage/horoscope.png"/>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" >
                        <Button Name="btnWeather" Click="btnWeather_Click">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/FrontPage/whether.png"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Name="btnLoadshedding" Click="btnLoadshedding_Click">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/FrontPage/loadshedding.png"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Name="btnGoldSilver" Click="btnGoldSilver_Click">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/FrontPage/gold_silver rates.png"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Name="btnTheatre" Click="btnTheatre_Click">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/FrontPage/theater.png"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Name="btnCalendar" Click="btnCalendars">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/FrontPage/horoscope.png"/>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>              
        </StackPanel  > 
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Border Name="TitleBorder" Grid.Row="1"
             Background="#FF264778" Opacity="0.7"
             Margin="0,260,0,0" 
             Height="{Binding ElementName=TitleText, Path=Height}" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top">

        <TextBlock Name="txt_lastest_update" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   
                   Text="keep in view"
                   Foreground="White" 
                   FontSize="22"
                   Margin="12" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: (Welcome to SO :) ) You should add some description about what your question is, not only some link - you know, that page can go 404 and this piece of information will be lost. (It is a [rule](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on SO -- this way, you will get downvoted)

Answer (score 0):

hey i think your problem is, you want keep your textblock fixed while list is scroll. so you have to keep your list in different grid and textblock in different grid which need to fix. and make grid which contain list scrolable = true.

Comment: .Thanks for your reply.What i need is  everything scrolls while scrolling but the text block should remain in view at top. My problem is similar to above link which i mentioned before.

Comment: The solution in This answer will give you that effect!